Permanently Block "A program is trying to access email address information stored in Outlook" dialog
Every time I restart my computer, some startup application tries to access my email address information via Outlook. I get this standard pop-up:

I click Deny every time. But I would like to be able to permanently turn off whatever app this is that is trying to get my email, or just uninstall the app. But Outlook doesn't tell me what app it is.
How can I figure out which app is doing this?

Use AutoRuns to disable any application that is automatically installed.  Verify your settings match your needs. You will have to enable each program individually to see which application is causing this dialog to appear. We don't have a list of programs running on your system, so we can't tell you which application it is.

So trial and error and process of elimination? Isn't there a way to figure out which application triggered the dialog while the dialog is up?

ProcessExplorer, but it might help, if you disable all applications from automatically starting and confirm the problem actually goes away.
